# Parse the output of my bash script and save as CSV

Tags: regex, string, bash, csv, parsing

I have a bash script that SSH'es to a list of servers (given a `.txt` file), runs another script inside each server, and shows the results. But I need to parse the verbose data from output, and eventually save some meaningful results as a `.CSV` file.

Here is my main script:

```
set +e
while read line
do
    ssh myUser@"$line" -t 'sudo su /path/to/script.sh' < /dev/null
done < "/home/listOfServers.txt"
```

where the `listOfServers.txt` is like

```
server1
server2
server3
```

The output of running my script looks like this, showing the results for each servers one after another.

```
     SNAME:WORKFLOW_APS_001     |10891    | Alive:2018-06-18:06:54          |TCP
     SNAME:WORKFLOW_APSWEB_001     |11343    | Alive:2018-06-18:06:54          |TCP
    Processes in Instance: WORKFLOW_OHS_002
    WORKFLOW_OHS_002                 | OHS                |    8925 | Alive    |  852960621 |  1367120 | 510:11:51 | http:9881
    Processes in Instance: WORKFLOW_OHS_003
    WORKFLOW_OHS_003                 | OHS                |    9187 | Alive    | 2041606684 |  1367120 | 510:11:51 | http:9883
     SNAME:WORKFLOW_RPSF_001     |10431    | Alive:2018-06-18:06:55          |TCP
     SNAME:WORKFLOW_SCPTL_001     |9788    | Alive:2018-06-18:06:55          |TCP
...
```

From this output, I only need the `OHS` names and their status, and save along with the original server's name as a CSV. The pattern to me looks like this: I need to look at each line, and if the line doesn't contain `"Processes in Instance"` or `"SNAME"`, then split based on space, and grab the 1st (OHS name) and 4th field (status). So my CSV will look like:

```
server1, WORKFLOW_OHS_002, Alive
server1, WORKFLOW_OHS_003, Alive
server2, .....
...
```

How can I modify my bash to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
while read -r line; do
    ssh myUser@"$line" -t 'sudo su /path/to/script.sh' < /dev/null |
    awk -v s="$line" -F '|' -v OFS=', ' '!/^[[:blank:]]*SNAME:/ && NF>2 {
       gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/, "");
       gsub(/[[:blank:]]*\|[[:blank:]]*/, "|");
       print s, $1, $4
    }'
done < "/home/listOfServers.txt"
```

---

**EDIT:** As per your comment below, you can do this to handle error conditions:

```
while read -r line; do
    out=$(ssh myUser@"$line" -t 'sudo su /path/to/script.sh' < /dev/null 2>&1)
    if [[ -z $out ]]; then
       echo "$line, NULL, NULL"
    elif [[ $out == *"timed out"* ]]; then
       echo "$line, FAIL, FAIL"
    else
       awk -v s="$line" -F '|' -v OFS=', ' '!/^[[:blank:]]*SNAME:/ && NF>2 {
          gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/, "");
          gsub(/[[:blank:]]*\|[[:blank:]]*/, "|");
          print s, $1, $4
       }' <<< "$out"
    fi
done < "/home/listOfServers.txt"
```

Comment: Sry for asking- I'm new to bash. I think this is a condition syntax problem in bash.

Comment: I think the problem is due to that `2>&1`!

Comment: Still shows FAIL as NULL. When I replace that with `2>/dev/null`, another behavior!

Answer (score 1):

Something to try - and good luck.

```
while read line
do  ssh myUser@"$line" -t 'sudo su /path/to/script.sh' < /dev/null |
        sed -E "/Processes in Instance/d; /SNAME/d;
        s/^ *([^| ]*) *[|][^|]*[|][^|]*[|] *([^| ]*).*/$line,\1,\2/;" 
done < "/home/listOfServers.txt"
```

You ought to be able to improve on that. :)

Comment: Looks like you are missing the original server name as the first CSV field! It shows right now as `,WORKFLOW_OHS_002,Alive`

Comment: That `$s` at the end should be `$line` I guess!

Comment: OOPS! Apologies. Used a shorter variable for testing and forgot to correct it here. Mea culpa, I fixed it, but yes, you got it. :)